# passing BlocProvider with class parameters

Tags: flutter, dart

in one of my classes in application i want to pass `BlocProvider` with class parameter, for example:

```
enum MenuItems{
  dashboard,
  tutorials,
  logout
}

class DashboardItems {
  MenuItems menuItem;
  BlocProvider action;

  DashboardItems(
      {
        @required this.menuItem,
        @required this.action
      }
  );
}
```

in that with `action` field i try to pass this method:

```
BlocProvider.of<MyEvent>(context).dispatch(MyEvent(event)))
```

such as:

```
DashboardItems(
    menuItem: MenuItems.dashboard,
    action:   BlocProvider.of<FragmentBloc>(context).dispatch(FragmentEvent(fragmentHome))),
```

is any solution to pass and use that?

Comment: i don't get why your action type is BlocProvider but you want to pass function to it. maybe you should change the type of 'action' param to your 'dispatch' function's output type.

Comment: @alisamawi because of i have some menu items and for one of them i have different action

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are passing not a function but a result of the function.

```
DashboardItems(
  menuItem: MenuItems.dashboard,
  // pass function here:
  action: () { BlocProvider.of<FragmentBloc>(context).dispatch(FragmentEvent(fragmentHome));}


class DashboardItems {
  MenuItems menuItem;
  Function action; //Change type from BlocProvider to Function.

  DashboardItems(
      {
        @required this.menuItem,
        @required this.action
      }
  );
}
```

Comment: i get this error now:  `error: The argument type 'Null Function()' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'BlocProvider<Bloc>'. (argument_type_not_assignable at    .    Only static members can be accessed in initializers.`

Comment: can you provide DashboardItems widget?

Comment: try this one(I've update the answer), if it would help, we will need to have DashboardItem Widget for a closer look.

Comment: i accepted your answer to get free time to check that